# Some one Cracked My android app and republished

Tags: android, google-play

Some one download my apk file from Google play and he changed package name and icons then republished in Google play market. How is this possible? How can I stop?

Comment: Not a specific programming problem.  I would ask at http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Question belongs to android.stackexchange.com

Comment: quick question, how did u discover this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't use `ProGaurd` to secure your app, It is quite easy to reverse engineer Android applications, so if you want to prevent this from happening, you should use `ProGuard` for its main function: obfuscation.

An example of program used to do the decode Android apps [APKTool](http://www.miui-au.com/add-ons/apktool/)

Comment: Thank you I will use ProGaurd. How can i Complain to play store for that publisher? which forum i need submit complaint?

Comment: I tried to find a link that may solve this issue, but unfortunately i couldnt find. so i suggest to go to your developer console, on the top left corner you have `Help & Feedback`, try to ask them there. hope they can help you.

Comment: There is a button in the Play Market app that allows you to report bad developers or apps.